# Live video from raw tcp packets

Tags: python, video, tcp, ffmpeg, scapy

we are trying to make a small python app that display a live video from sniffed packets using `scapy` and `ffplay`. This is part of our master degree research project. The goal is to make a proof of concept app that spies on video transimitted over tcp.
We have a working script that writes into a `.dat` file and then we read it using `ffplay`. It works ok but have a lot of latency and we think we could do better : directly stream it into `ffplay` without the need to write raw data in a file.

Here's our script :

```
from scapy.all import * 
import os

export_dat = open("data.dat", "a")

def write_packet_raw(packet):
    export_dat.write(str(packet.getlayer(Raw)))

def realtime_packet():
    p = sniff(iface="wlan0", filter="tcp and (port 5555)", count=5000, prn=write_packet_raw)

realtime_packet()
export_dat.close()
```

And then we launch : `ffplay -window_title Videostream -framedrop -infbuf -f h264 -i data.dat`

Any idea on how we can achieve that ? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write to `stdout` in binary mode instead of a file and pipe the output to `ffplay`.

```
import sys
sys.stdout.buffer.write(...)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Then run it like:

`python3 sniff.py | ffplay -f h264 -i -`

The `-` means `stdin`.

Comment: Thanks we found our own solution but that's pretty much what we did !